# How to award the bounty

Tags: support

I put a bounty on a question, accepted the answer but now it is community awarded?

It is just a matter of feel-good to not let it be auto-rewarded but I would like to know what I have to do to actually reward it myself.

I am probably just overlooking the answer to this but once you overlooked something it is hard to find, so asking will be a lot quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually award a bounty, you need to click the bounty icon next to the answer you've chosen. It looks a faded version of the icon that appears after a bounty is won by an answer:

[image]

Accepting an answer does not explicitly award a bounty. You could, for example, bounty a different answer if you chose. However, since you accepted an answer **and** did not explicitly award the bounty to anyone, the full bounty was automatically awarded to the answer you accepted once the grace period expired. Had you not accepted an answer, then *half* the bounty would have been awarded to the highest scoring answer (with a score of at least 2) posted after your bounty began.

Additional information can be found in the Help Center article: [What is a bounty?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Oh my. What does the second of our posts say? Same minute at least, probably you were a little faster to push the button as your answer is on top of mine now :)

Comment: The timestamp claims mine was 34 seconds faster :P

Comment: And apparently I got a hat in the process of making that screenshot. Neat.

Comment: OK: Congrats then :) Oh: and screenshots earn awards? Then I should have gotten one today as well (but didn't). Nevermind, got a secret hat instead :)

Comment: It was actually for [starting a bounty](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/gelt), so you could go do that too! I just immediately refunded it after I took the screenshot, and didn't even realize I would end up with a hat..

Comment: What's the difference between a head-hunter and a hat-hunter, heh? #D

Answer (score 0):

You will have to award the bounty before it expires. One day before that happens, you get a reminder, then there's a "grace period" – and if you missed that, too, community awards it to either the accepted answer (if any), or the highest rated one.

The above is the short variant – a longer one should be [somewhere in our help pages](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) ;)

### TL;DR:

> #### How is a bounty awarded?
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Comment: My problem was I could not find a button for rewarding the bounty, always remains difficult to ask a question which can not be misinterpret :-S